# SQL developer won't start

Tags: windows-xp, sqldeveloper

Today I tried to open SQL developer and it won't start at all.

I am using Windows XP and I haven't been using SQL Developer for 1 or 2 months. Today, when I tried to open SQL Developer, I click the shortcut, and the cursor showed up a funnel and then turned back to normal sharpe.

I rebooted multiple times, press the real `sql_developer.exe`, download a new copy of SQL Developer and all is in vain.

Last time I used SQL Developer and it is quite normal.

My laptop is lenovo 3000 c200.

**Edit, I tried the following action and all of them didn't work:**

1. install display card driver(Intel GMA 950 Graphics Core)
2. install Lenovo Systems ToolBox for Windows
3. install Lenovo Care Pack
4. Safe Mode
5. Clean Registry
6. Dl new copy of sql developer(no jre)
7. reset bios setting in the bios menu

***Now it is working. I dl a new copy of sql developer with jre, and it works! My jre must have been corrupted. Problem solved!***

Comment: phaaa hidden deamon  beacuse I see warning and errors come from, btw +1,

Comment: It is so weird because my Eclipse is fine running program with Java!